# Open-source location based services system

Tags: open-source, .net, ecommerce, geo-location

Is there any open-source Location based Services E-commerce system like Foodpanda or www.bookmyspa.in where the user selects his location first based on which the vendors are displayed. I prefer one built on .NET framework. I suppose NOPCOMMERCE is not one such?